# Shiny widget does not pass values correctly to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have the shiny dashboard below in which I want to use a variable from my `pickerInput()` and create a plot. The issue is that if I use ,for example `name` or `snID` instead of `input$DB` the plot is created. But when I use `input$DB` I get: `Warning: Error in table: all arguments must have the same length`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "My dashboard"),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
        uiOutput("dbs")

    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
        plotlyOutput("fn")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

        sts<-c("Rev","Rev")
        sID<-c("123","124")
        snID<-c("23","34")
        name<-c("s","d")
        pe<-data.frame(sts,sID,snID,name)



    output$dbs<-renderUI({

            pickerInput("DB", "Select Database/s", 
                        choices = c("name","snID"), 
                        multiple = F,options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                        selected = "name")

    })
    output$fn<-renderPlotly({

            #2.2 MAKING A TABLE for public.exists
        tbl<-table(pe[[input$DB]], pe$sts)
            ggplotly(
                ggplot(as.data.frame(tbl), aes(!!sym(input$DB), Freq, fill = sts)) 
            )

    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The problem is that `input$DB` gives a character, which is incompatible with `table()`. Using `table(pe[[input$DB]], pe$sts)` should work better. And you should put `!!sym(input$DB)` instead of `input$DB` in `ggplot()` for the same reason

Comment: that worked finally

Comment: Create a new answer from my comment so that people can see what was wrong and the full working code

Comment: your solution does not work if pe is a reactive object. Should I make a new Q?

Comment: Try to replace `pe` by `pe()`

Comment: It gives object 'name' not found

Comment: I created a new Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62071152/cannot-find-column-name-of-a-reactive-dataframe-in-a-shiny-app and will accept your answer for this one.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `output$fn` reactive is executing before `input$DB` has a value.  Therefore, add

`req(input$DB)`

at the start of the reactive, and you should be OK.

In the absence of any demo input data, it's difficult to be definitive.

Comment: there is demo data at the start of my server part

Comment: can u replicate it?

Comment: Your problem is not with Shiny or ggplot.  As the error message says, it's with your call to `table`.  You keep changing your source code in response to @bretauv's suggestions.  He seems to be pointing you in the right direction but you do seem to have multiple issues with your code.  I suggest taking a step back and working through the problem piece by piece so that you can isolate and understand each problem in turn.

Comment: his answer helped me but now I have a diiferent issue here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62071152/cannot-find-column-name-of-a-reactive-dataframe-in-a-shiny-app